# Validation failed for one or more entities issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

This is truly one of the strangest issues I've run into.

I have a Web API which uses EF. I have an audit table which takes an ApplicationUser. I create the new object, add it to the collection and then call SaveChangesAsync(). The weird part is, I get "User name MyUserName is already taken." error.

```
using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
{
    var user = context.Users.Single<ApplicationUser>(x => x.UserName == model.UserName);

    var sid = context.SessionIds.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == model.SessionId);

    var audit = new Audit
    {
        Data = model.Data,
        User = user,
        IpAddress = Helper.GetClientIp(Request),
        Session = sid != null ? sid : ItsMyChance.Entities.Entities.SessionId.Create(scoreModel.UserName, scoreModel.GameId)
    };

    context.Audits.Add(audit);
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

**Update**

This code has been working for years. The difference is I upgrade from .NET 4.5 to .NET 4.61

**Update 2**

I also tried the following but still receive the same error

```
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
```

**Update 3**

Trying to track this issue down I call

```
var entries = context.ChangeTracker.Entries();
```

It returns several entries, 1 for each object, including User. User shows Added and another as Unchanged. I can't figure out how this is happening.

In addition, I added the following before making any changes but there's no effect.

```
context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since You are adding the complete user object in Audit , so SaveChangesAsync will save a new Entry for Audit and User also and since a user with same username already exists that's why you are getting this error. What you should do is just assign just the UserId (Whatever is referral key in Audit table for User) in Audit object

```
var audit = new Audit
    {
        Data = model.Data,
        UserId = user.Id,
        IpAddress = Helper.GetClientIp(Request),
        Session = sid != null ? sid : ItsMyChance.Entities.Entities.SessionId.Create(scoreModel.UserName, scoreModel.GameId)
    };
```

Comment: The code has been working for years. I upgraded from .NET 4.5 to 4.61 and now it doesn't work.
I'm pretty sure that EF knows that user already exists in the collection so it doesn't make sense for it to attempt to create a new one.